# Any equivalent of __asm int 3 in managed C#?

Tags: c#, debugging

Is there a way to forcibly trigger a debug break from a C# program similar to injecting an "int 3" instruction into a native program?

My use case: a custom "Exception" dialog where I can press the "Debug" button and immediately switch to the Visual Studio window showing me the location and the call stack (rather than switching manually, using "break all" and selecting a GUI thread). It only has to work if I am ALREADY debugging my program.

Comment: Debugger.Break() is the same.  Calling it from a button's Click event handler, no, don't expect to see much of interest.

Comment: It can be useful when chasing bugs that only happen under weird circumstances, and a conditional breakpoint introduces unacceptable performance degradation. Or, when the execution path to recreate the bug is difficult to determine. Works great in a dedicated thread to minimize Heisenberg's Debugger Effect.